# How many elements in string array?

Tags: c

I want to find how many names in `names` array. I know `sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0])` gives the right answer. But the problem is I can't just declare `char *names[];`. Because compiler gives me an error like this ***"Storage of names is unknown"***. To avoid this error, I must declare like this `char *names[] = {"somename", "somename2"};`. But the thing is I cannot assign the strings right after deceleration. I assign strings after some conditions and my problem is how many strings i have after that conditions.

My example.

```
char *names[];
char word[10];
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(word, sizeof(word), fp)>0) {

  // Think hello increase every time loop returns. 
  // such as "hello1", and the 2nd time "hello2"
  if(strcmp(word, "hello1") == 0)
    names[i] = word;
  }
  printf("size: %d\n", sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]));
```

Comment: Then use `malloc` to dynamically allocate storage.

Comment: Nothing is clear (*to me*). Can you please show an example of what you have tried?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth how can i use `malloc`.

Comment: I agree. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: To use `malloc` (effectively) you need to know the number of names first. This is possibly an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I added a simple example. I don't know number of names in any case.

Comment: People use things like `sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0])` when the number of things to be counted is known before the storage for those things is allocated. It doesn't make any sense to use that kind of code in your situation.

Comment: Your code calls `fscanf` but passes parameters that should be passed to `fread`. How can that work? And there are other questionable things. Perhaps you should try to get a simpler program to work and then build your way up to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is obviously code that is hacked together without thought or even an attempt at understanding.   Any explanation will be pointless, since any explanation will rely on some understanding of the basics of C and of the functions being used.   As such, answers will be unhelpful to the person who asked the question, and the question is unhelpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

An array size is **fixed** once the array is created.  It cannot change.

---

If `fp` can be read twice, read the file once for the word count.

```
size_t word_count = 0;
int word_length_max = 0;

long pos = ftell(fp); // remember file location
int n = 0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%*s%n", &n) != EOF && n > 0) {  // Use %n to record character count
  word_count++;
  if (n > word_length_max) {
    word_length_max = n; 
  }
  n = 0; 
}
```

Now code knows the `word[]` array size needed and the maximum length.

```
char *words[word_count];
char word[word_length_max + 1u];  // buffer size needed to read in the words

fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET); // go back
for (size_t i=0; i<word_count; i++) {
  if (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != 1) {
    Handle_UnexpectedError(); // 2nd pass should have same acceptable results
  }
  words[i] = strdup(word); // allocate a duplicate 
}
```

When done with `words[]`, be sure to free the allocated memory.

```
....  
for (size_t i=0; i<word_count; i++) {
  free(words[i]);
}
```

Better code would also check the return value of `ftell(), fseek(), malloc()` for errors and limit `fscanf(fp, "%s", word)`.